# Generating bip39 mnemonic in VueJS, getting error Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using VueJS v3 and trying to generate and display a BIP39 mnemonic using the `bip39` library. However I am getting an error in the browser console:

```sh
Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined  _stream_readable.js:48:20
    js _stream_readable.js:48
    __require chunk-PWNRNYY6.js:23
    js readable-browser.js:1
    __require chunk-PWNRNYY6.js:23
    js index.js:3
    __require chunk-PWNRNYY6.js:23
    js index.js:3
    __require chunk-PWNRNYY6.js:23
    js browser.js:3
    __require chunk-PWNRNYY6.js:23
    js index.js:3
    __require chunk-PWNRNYY6.js:23
    <anonymous> bip39:1

    js _stream_readable.js:48
    __require chunk-PWNRNYY6.js:23
    js readable-browser.js:1
    __require chunk-PWNRNYY6.js:23
    js index.js:3
    __require chunk-PWNRNYY6.js:23
    js index.js:3
    __require chunk-PWNRNYY6.js:23
    js browser.js:3
    __require chunk-PWNRNYY6.js:23
    js index.js:3
    __require chunk-PWNRNYY6.js:23
    <anonymous> bip39:1
    InnerModuleEvaluation self-hosted:2393
    InnerModuleEvaluation self-hosted:2393
    InnerModuleEvaluation self-hosted:2393
    InnerModuleEvaluation self-hosted:2393
    evaluation self-hosted:2354
```

```js
<script setup>
import { generateMnemonic } from "bip39";
import {ref} from "vue";
let mnemonic = ref(null);
mnemonic.value = generateMnemonic();
</script>

<template>
  <div v-if="mnemonic !== null">
   <h1>{{ mnemonic }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>
```

Package.json

```json
{
  "name": "vue-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview --port 5050"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bip39": "^3.0.4",
    "pinia": "^2.0.11",
    "vue": "^3.2.31",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^2.2.2",
    "vite": "^2.8.4"
  }
}
```

I can get this working outside of Vue in a plain `.js`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Here's a live demo for a working solution: 
 https://codesandbox.io/s/bip39-vue-demo-5nlzy4

Got to say though, I didn't have an easy time trying out that module. I think its designed to be run server-side, and not in the browser like this. There may also be some security considerations to take account for if you're using this in production, but that's a separate issue.

*Here's a [working](https://5nlzy4.csb.app/) Vue component I built to demonstrate usage:*

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
      <div v-if="mnemonic">
        <p><b>Result</b>: {{ mnemonic }} </p>
      </div>
      <div v-else>Loading....</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import { mnemonicToSeed } from 'bip39';

export default {
  name: "GenerateMnemonic",
  props: {
    msg: String
  },
   data() {
    return {
      mnemonic: null,  
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    mnemonicToSeed('basket actual')
      .then(bytes => bytes.toString('hex'))
      .then((result) => {
        this.mnemonic = result;
      });
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.hello {
  max-width: 500px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
  border: 1px solid #2c3e50;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate the effort in the answer. Unfortunately it still didn't work for me, but after a bit of testing I think it has to do with me using Vue3 and maybe Vite. Looks like it works with Vue2.

Comment: For those wanting to use Vue3 + Vite I found this package to work but it seems fairly obscure and doesn't have a lot of usage. https://github.com/paulmillr/scure-bip39